# Adding days between dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add 14 days to the data that ranges from 01-JAN-2011 to 12-DEC-2018. Below is the query I wrote.

```
update (RENTAL_DATE +14) where RENTAL_DATE between '01-JAN-17' and '12-DEC-18'from MRE_COMP_DATA;
```

RENTAL_DATE IS A DATE COLUMN AND WE WANT TO ADD 14 DAYS TO IT.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: That's not even close to correct SQL syntax. What source are you learning SQL from?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Correct syntax is `Update TABLE_NAME set Column1= <expression> Where <condition>`. In this syntax where clause is optional.

Comment: Here is another query I wrote..

Comment: Select RENTAL_date,  
       RENTAL_DATE+14 add_14_days   
  from MRE_COMP_DATA WHERE RENTAL_DATE between '01-JAN-17' and '12-DEC-18' ;

Comment: Refer to the answer below by DDS

Comment: It is not a smart way to compare `DATE` values with **strings**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have used a wrong syntax::

```
UPDATE mre_comp_data
SET rental_date = rental_date + 14
WHERE RENTAL_DATE between '01-JAN-17' and '12-DEC-18'
```

Here is a link to PL-SQL update syntax: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm)

Comment: ahh ok, I wrote it the otherway around..  SET RENTAL_date,  
       RENTAL_DATE+14 add_14_days   
  from MRE_COMPETITOR_DATA WHERE RENTAL_DATE between '01-JAN-17' and '12-DEC-18' ;

Comment: This way of writing dates relies on the NLS settings of your clients; a safe way could be by the ANSI syntax, for example `date '2017-01-01'`